# Data from HTML to PHP is always null

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, input

I am working to a register login page with php and html. But my php code cannot see the data sent from php.
Down are my html and php files.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href = '../css/login.css' rel = 'stylesheet'>
    <title> Login </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="../php/login.php" method="post">
    <input id = "loginButton" type="image" src ="../images/loginAndRegister.gif" alt="submit">
    <div class = "panel">

        <p> Login </p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label> username </label>
        <br>
        <input type = "text" name = "username" required>
        <br>
        <label> password </label>
        <br>
        <input type = "password" name = "password" required>
        <br>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<html>
    <body>
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "dark_souls";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $user = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : NULL;
    $pass = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : NULL;
    echo $user;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$user."' AND password = '".$pass."'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      header("Location: ../templates/Home.html");
    } else {
      echo "Wrong Credentials";
    }
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I have writted that "echo $user" in the php code just to check if it is working. The problem is that I used EXACTLY the same code for register ant there it worked.
Help please!

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to **sql injection** so use **prepared statements with parameters** instead see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php and **don't store passwords in plain text** use php hashing for that https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php

Comment: @Dharman Thank you for the advice. Can I do this also for inserting a password in the database. For register for example. Or it is a different procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because the form doesn't have a submit button.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: user has a button <input id = "loginButton" type="image" src ="../images/loginAndRegister.gif" alt="submit">

Comment: @nbk Image inputs won't process POST arrays. So the answer stands to be right.

Comment: @fthe code calls login.php with a username and password, it is bad programmed, but it works essentially even without the code provided in this answer